# binary document classifcation

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I know this is a very vague question but I'm trying to figure out the best way to do document classification. I have two sets training and testing. The training set is a set of documents each labeled 1 or 0. The documents are labeled 1 if is it a informative summary and a 0 if it is not. I'm trying to create a supervised classifier. I can't decide which nlp toolkit to use. I'm thinking nltk. Do you have any suggestions? I have to write the classifier in python. Also any specific types of classifiers. I've been doing research but can't seem to get a good answer.

Comment: It might just be me, but it seems pretty unclear what you're asking here - Can you try rephrasing exactly what you want to do, maybe even with an example of the data you're dealing with?

Comment: @MattCoubrough It's a relatively clear question in my eyes, but one that's probably too broad for SO. The short answer is that there are a wide number that all perform differently on different datasets.

Comment: Okay np. I thought it was a bit vague but wasn't sure. I thought of naive bayes but it doesn't achieve the precision I would like and wasn't sure what to do next

Comment: @user3750474 it's not quite vague, just an underconstrained problem. My answer goes into a little more depth, but the truth is that it's really hard to know ahead of time what accuracy you'll be able to achieve.

Comment: @user3750474 if you describe your dataset better, it would be easier to give a more accurate answer. But as I mentioned in my answer Naive Bayes and SVM are you best options.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that is really depends. The reason that you haven't found a great resource yet is because document classification, as of yet, is still a relatively new, and poorly understood field. The truth of the matter is that there are a huge number of different classifiers that could potentially work, and it's not really possible to say which classifier will be the best for your specific task, and it's very dataset-dependent.

The best advice I can give you is that there are generally two steps when it comes to running one of these classifiers. The first is vectorization, which is putting your documents into a fixed-length vector representation. The most common is `tfidf` weighting, which is implemented quite well in sklearn. Specific documentation found here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting

Once you've vectorized the input you then need to choose a classifier and an accuracy metric. As for classifiers, I would suggest you just browse the examples shown [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html), and choose the one that returns the best accuracy metric.

As far as accuracy metrics go, the two simplest ones (there are also many very complex alternatives), would be simple accuracy, and `AUC`, both are supported by sklearn. AUC is a more robust version of accuracy that is more robust to class imbalance (if 99.9% if all your examples are 1, then a classifier only predicting 1's shouldn't be the best classifier out there)

This is actually a pretty broad subject, and there's a huge amount to cover, but if you glue together some sklearn functions you should be able to get something workable pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Would you recommend scikit learn vs nltk?

Comment: Yes. 100% without a doubt. `nltk` is very old-school, very slow, and has generally less functionality. It is nice to get in and start with, but most of it's benefit is wrapping a couple of academic datasets.

Answer (score 2):

I generally recommend using Scikit as Slater suggested. Its more scalable than NLTK. For this task using Naive Bayes Classifier or Support Vector Machine is your best bet. You are dealing with binary classification so you don't have multi classes. 
As for the features that you should extract, try unigrams, bigrams, trigrams, and TFIDF features. Also, LDA might turn out useful, but start with the easier ones such as unigrams. 
This also depends on the type and length of texts you are dealing with. Document classification has been around for more than a decade and there are so many good papers that you could find useful.
Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are useful and informative, but may not address the entire problem. You phrased your question in terms of 'document classification', and the approaches recommended are sensible solutions for that problem. But if I read your question right, it's not really a traditional [document classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification) problem. The question states:

> The documents are labeled 1 if is it a informative summary and a 0 if it is not.

Most document classification systems assign each document to one of a set of classes. E.g. 'Document 1 is in the 'Sports' class, document 2 is in 'Art', ...

Your problem might be closer to [textual entailment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_entailment), which attempts to discern whether one document (usually a short statement or a summary) is implied by another (usually longer) document. You might also look into [automatic summarization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization) a bit. That field deals with generating summaries (whereas you're only interested in scoring them), but many summarization systems also include scoring and ranking, used to choose between a set of candidate summaries. (Apologies for posting a sequence of Wikipedia links, but perhaps at least some reference to terms for a few standard NLP tasks will help.)

There's another key issue that isn't (currently) addressed in the question: If document x is labeled as 'an informative summary', what is it an informative summary of?

For example, consider the statement:

> "An automatic summarization system attempts to generate a short, readable abstract of a longer document"

That might be an informative summary of one of the Wikipedia pages linked above. But it's certainly not an appropriate summary of the others! It seems your classifier might need access to the larger text that a document is (supposedly) summarizing in order to determine whether the summary is a good one.

If you have access to said documents, you might also consider framing your problem as an Information Retrieval task - e.g., use the candidate summary as a query, and score its 'usefulness' by the ranking of the target document in the results returned. If this approach is workable, you'd benefit from Lucene and other well engineered IR tools.